# Is the .net DbProviderFactory thread safe?

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, multithreading, dbproviderfactories

I'm refactoring some old code based on `DbProviderFactory` to take advantage of connection pooling, but I ran into a simple question: Is the object returned by `DbProviderFactories.GetFactory()` thread-safe?

The code now is this:

```
DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("Provider String from config");
var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = "connection string from config";
```

etc, etc.  But this is done once PER THREAD.  Obviously not what I'd want.

I wondered if I can use the "factory" object everywhere?  Can I create multiple connections in different threads from the same `DbProviderFactory` object?  Can I create `DbAdapter` classes, again, from the same factory?

As stupid as it is, the MSDN doc for even the concrete sub-classes don't say if you can do this.  For example the [msdn doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlclientfactory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `SqlClientFactory` for the `CreateDataAdapter()` method doesn't say if it's thread-safe or not.  A few different guides on the internet have about just opening an instance of `SqlConnection` and it'll do thread-pooling, which is fine, but if you then do this:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("my connection string);
DbDataAdapter adapt = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(connection).CreateDataAdapter();
```

Is that thread-safe?  How many of *those* factories exist?  What does that `GetFactory` method there return across threads?  Always the same object?  Or not?  My existing code that I'm modifying uses `DbDataAdapter`s heavily, so I don't really want to change all of that too.

So is it thread-safe to take the factory and use it from multiple threads?

Answer (score 1):

**[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbproviderfactory.aspx)** says:-

> **Thread Safety:**
>
> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are
> thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread
> safe.

Comment: Ya that's the default message for virtually every class in the library.  And considering there is no appreciable documentation for anything else in the class, that means "they haven't gotten around to documenting it yet" IMO.

Comment: @Kevin:- Yes even IMO I would agree to it!